# iOS c# adding JSON data to a tableView

Tags: c#, ios, list, xamarin, tableview

I cant figure this out. It seems that all of the data is getting into the list countryNames, but out of the function GetCountries() the list appears empty. Any help would be greatly appreciated. When i print the list to the console within the GetCountries function it prints out all of the data, but outside the list is empty.

```
namespace Test
{
  public partial class StartViewController : UIViewController
  {
    private List<String> countryNames;
    //private List<String> countryLanguages;

    public StartViewController() : base("StartViewController", null)
    {
        countryNames = new List<String>();
        GetCountries();

        // function to get country names and languages
        async Task GetCountries()
        {
            List<CountryInfo> countries;
            countries = await RefreshDataAsync();

            foreach (var c in countries)
            {
                countryNames.Add(c.name);
            }
        }

    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        CountriesTableView.Source = new StartViewController.TableSource(countryNames, this);
    }

    public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewDidAppear(animated);
    }

    #region TableView source stuff
    public class TableSource : UITableViewSource
    {
        StartViewController vc;
        private List<String> countries;
        //private List<String> languages;

        public TableSource(List<String> countriesIn, StartViewController vc_in)
        {
            countries = countriesIn;
            vc = vc_in;
        }

        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            UITableViewCell cell;
            // try to get a reusable cell
            cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell("countries");
            if (cell == null)
            {
                cell = new UITableViewCell( UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, "countries");
            }

            return cell;
        }

        public override nint NumberOfSections(UITableView tableView)
        {
            return 1;  
        }

        public override string TitleForHeader(UITableView tableView, nint section)
        {
            return " ";
        }

        public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    // A task that calls other awaitable async methods
    public async Task<List<CountryInfo>> RefreshDataAsync()
    {

        HttpClient client;
        client = new HttpClient();

        var uri = new Uri("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all");


        var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
        List<CountryInfo> Items = null;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();


            Items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CountryInfo>>(content);
        }

        return Items;
    }

    #region Json helpers   use http://json2csharp.com/  paste in json or url of service and it generates classes for you
    public class Currency
    {
        public string code { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string symbol { get; set; }
    }

    public class Language
    {
        public string iso639_1 { get; set; }
        public string iso639_2 { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string nativeName { get; set; }
    }

    public class Translations
    {
        public string de { get; set; }
        public string es { get; set; }
        public string fr { get; set; }
        public string ja { get; set; }
        public string it { get; set; }
        public string br { get; set; }
        public string pt { get; set; }
        public string nl { get; set; }
        public string hr { get; set; }
        public string fa { get; set; }
    }

    public class CountryInfo
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public List<string> topLevelDomain { get; set; }
        public string alpha2Code { get; set; }
        public string alpha3Code { get; set; }
        public List<string> callingCodes { get; set; }
        public string capital { get; set; }
        public List<object> altSpellings { get; set; }
        public string region { get; set; }
        public string subregion { get; set; }
        public int population { get; set; }
        public List<object> latlng { get; set; }
        public string demonym { get; set; }
        public double? area { get; set; }
        public double? gini { get; set; }
        public List<string> timezones { get; set; }
        public List<object> borders { get; set; }
        public string nativeName { get; set; }
        public string numericCode { get; set; }
        public List<Currency> currencies { get; set; }
        public List<Language> languages { get; set; }
        public Translations translations { get; set; }
        public string flag { get; set; }
        public List<object> regionalBlocs { get; set; }
        public string cioc { get; set; }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably that `ViewDidLoad` is being called before you get the `countryNames` back from your web service. `GetCountries` is an async method, so it returns a `Task` right away and the constructor finishes and returns immediately after, so the OS is now free to call `ViewDidLoad`, which it does... but you are still awaiting the web request results so `countryNames` is still an empty list when you call `CountriesTableView.Source = new StartViewController.TableSource(countryNames, this);`, thus the `countries` field is also an empty list, and that is where you are getting your data to display in the list from. So you need to update your source when `GetCountries` finishes... but you have no way to do that since you are not awaiting the call to `GetCountries`.

```
namespace Test
{
  public partial class StartViewController : UIViewController
  {
    // No need for this here, since your TableSource will be holding 
    // and providing your data
    //private List<String> countryNames;
    //private List<String> countryLanguages;

    public StartViewController() : base("StartViewController", null)
    {

        // Best Practice not to call async methods from a constructor
        // A constructor should be fast and return, after running all 
        // of its code, right away.
        //GetCountries();
    }


    public override async void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        // Get your data and then set your source
        var countries = await RefreshDataAsync();

        var countryNames = new List<string>();
        foreach (var c in countries)
        {
            countryNames.Add(c.name);
        }

        // since you awaited the above, countryNames is now populated
        // before you set up your TableSource. 
        CountriesTableView.Source = new StartViewController.TableSource(countryNames, this); 

        // On a side note, by passing and holding onto a reference to
        // this UIViewController, you are creating a circular reference
        // which will cause a memory leak. You should not need a reference
        // to this view controller from your TableSource.             
    }
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

There's that, and then looking at your `TableSource` code, you are not populating your cell with any data. You get and return the cell, but you did not set any of the UI controls, like `UILabel`s, text (or whatever) values to display your data. Also you need to tell the `UITableView` how many items you have to display by returning the number of items from the `RowsInSection` method. As it is, you are telling the `UITableView` that you only have one item. You need to do something like:

```
    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        UITableViewCell cell;
        // try to get a reusable cell
        cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell("countries");
        if (cell == null)
        {
            cell = new UITableViewCell( UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, "countries");
        }

         // Get data for row
         string countryName = countries[indexPath.Row];

         // Display data in the cell
         cell.TextLabel.Text = countryName;

         return cell;
    }

    public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {
        // return the number of items you need to display
        return countries.Count;
    }
```

If I were you, though, I would have your `TableSource` have a `List<CountryInfo>` field instead of a `List<string>`. That way your `TableSource` can provide any and all country data that a `UITableView` consuming it could possibly want to display.